# larger file upload problem with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload

I need to upload a csv file to a server. works fine for smaller files but when the file is 3-6 meg its not working.

```
$allowedExtensions = array("csv");
         foreach ($_FILES as $file) { 
            if ($file['tmp_name'] > '') { 
             if (!in_array(end(explode(".", strtolower($file['name']))), $allowedExtensions)) { 

              die($file['name'].' is an invalid file type!<br/>'. '<a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">'. '&lt;&lt Go Back</a>'); 

             }
             if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
                } else {
                    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
              }

             echo "File has been uploaded";



            }
```

//upload form

```
 <form name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<? echo $_SERVER['php_self'];?>?action=upload_process" method="POST">
                    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="31457280" />
                    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
                    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
            </form>
```

I have also added this to htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You didn't check the actual values. run `phpinfo()` to see them

Comment: If you do a phpinfo, what is the limit max_filesize etc. there? EDIT: Shrapnel beat me to it.

Comment: If you send with it the max file size, and compare the uploaded files against it, you will be letting any user pick the maximum file size.

Comment: upload_max_filesize is 2 meg in phpinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of $_FILES['userfile']['error']? Have a look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Also, whats with this:

```
if ($file['tmp_name'] > '') {
```

I don't think that's very healthy.

Comment: A better way may be `if (file_exists($file['tmp_name'])) {`

Comment: @donut: Even better is `is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])`, which has some additional script subversion protection.

Comment: @chris so the machine is telling you "UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini." - can you change the value in your php.ini?

Comment: its for a design client.. so i have no control over it.

I told him the problem and he asked me for a workaround- ie. ftp batch from desktop

Answer (score 0):

Just some suggestions to your code

- `($file['tmp_name'] > '')` should be something like `( ! empty($file['tmp_name']))`
- echoing "possible file upload attack" won't help anyone. If you believe it is a possible attack, log it to a file.
- The form action attribute, the `$_SERVER['php_self']` should be capitalised because it is a constant, i.e. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache error logs and the error should be there?

Answer (score -1):

Check your php.ini file and see if upload_max_filesize in there is set higher than 3 MB, I don't know if the .htaccess has precedence over the php.ini.

The default upload limit on debian php5 is 2MB if I recall correctly, but I am not sure what system you are running on.

You can also check the php values if you create a file *e.g. info.php* and **put it in the same directory as your "problem php script".**

The file content should look like this
`<?php
phpinfo();
?>`

This will *give you all php relevant values referring to the directory you are in*, hope it helps.